# dtoverlay parameters being ignored

Tags: x11, parameter, device-tree

Attempting to calibrate a touchscreen, only the first of *xmin*, *xmax*, *ymin*, *ymax* is accepted. No matter what order, only the first has any effect.

```
dtoverlay=ads7846,penirq=25,speed=10000,penirq_pull=2,xohms=150,xmin=200,xmax=3800,ymin=200,ymax=3800
```

System:

- Raspberry Pi
- Raspbian Jessie
- Makibes 5" resistive touch screen SPI interface XPT2046 chipset.

I also tried using a calibration file, `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf`, but that had no effect, although it did show in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

Any ideas what to look for?

Answer (score 0):

*dtoverlay* is truncated at 80 characters.
Not sure if this is just a raspbian jessie feature, but I dont immediately see any references to it outside RaspberryPi

see:  [Device Trees, overlays, and parameters](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/) Section 3.2